# How to use setFilter on the EntityCollectionService

Tags: ngrx, angular-ngrx-data

I would like to know how the setFilter method works for the EntityCollectionService in @ngrx/data.  The [documentation](https://ngrx.io/guide/data/entity-collection-service) hints at how it is used, but there is no example showing the actual setFilter(pattern: any) function being used.  Since the argument can be of type any, I cannot really infer what should be done here.

Basically, I have a list of objects in the data store using the @ngrx/data module.  I would like to define a filter so that I can subscribe to the filteredEntities$ observable of the EntityCollectionService.  I can successfully subscribe to the entities$ observable and receive the full unfiltered list.  Previously, I was doing the filtering outside of the EntityCollectionService, but I would like to utilize the built-in filtering mechanism.

```js
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  filteredProjects$: Observable<Project[]>;
  typeFilterOptions: FilterOption[];
  stageFilterOptions: FilterOption[];

  constructor(private projectService: ProjectEntityService, ptivate metadataService: MetadataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.typeFilterOptions = this.metadataService.getProjectTypes();
    this.stageFilterOptions = this.metadataService.getProjectStages();

    this.filteredProjects$ = this.projectService.filteredEntities$;
  }

  onFilterChange() {
    typeFilter = typeFilterOptions.filter(option => option.isChecked).map(option.name);
    stageFilter = stageFilterOptions.filter(option => option.isChecked).map(option.name);

    this.projectService.setFilter(project => {
      return (typeFilter.indexOf(project.type) >= 0) &&
             (stageFilter.indexOf(project.stage) >= 0); 
    }
  }
}
```

The above code is my best approach at trying to set the filter correctly.  Obviously, that is not working as I expected it would.  When setting the filter to a filter function nothing changes even though I can see the `set filter` action firing as expected.  The entities are still not being filtered at that point.  The argument being label as `pattern: any` make me think that it should be something other than a function, but again I cannot infer off of the documentation what it is expecting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so digging into the [source code](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/2964e2b6fae8bd667e59af3aa85189f8052c3d1b/modules/data/src/selectors/entity-selectors.ts#L193) I was able to figure out how to use the filter on an ngrx/data Entity Service.

The piece I was missing was defining the filter function in the Entity Service metadata configuration ([see docs here](https://ngrx.io/guide/data/entity-metadata#filterfn)):

**app.module.ts**

```js
const entityMetadata: EntityMetadataMap = {
  Project: {
    //pattern can be any object you want it to be.  This is the same argument used in setFilter(pattern: any)
    filterFn: (entities: Project[], pattern: {types: string[], stages: string[]}) => {
      return entitites.filter(entity => {
       return (pattern.types.indexOf(entity.type) >= 0) &&
              (pattern.stages.indexOf(entity.stage) >= 0)
      });
    }
  }
};

@NgModule({
    ...
})
export class AppModule {

    constructor(private eds: EntityDefinitionService) {

    eds.registerMetadataMap(entityMetadata);
  }
}
```

then in the component all you need to do is create the filter object and use it as the argument to setFilter on the Entity Service:

**my.component.ts**

```js
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  filteredProjects$: Observable<Project[]>;
  typeFilterOptions: FilterOption[];
  stageFilterOptions: FilterOption[];

  constructor(private projectService: ProjectEntityService, private metadataService: MetadataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.typeFilterOptions = this.metadataService.getProjectTypes();
    this.stageFilterOptions = this.metadataService.getProjectStages();

    this.filteredProjects$ = this.projectService.filteredEntities$;
  }

  onFilterChange() {
    typeFilter = typeFilterOptions.filter(option => option.isChecked).map(option.name);
    stageFilter = stageFilterOptions.filter(option => option.isChecked).map(option.name);

    this.projectService.setFilter({
      types: typeFilter,
      stages: stageFilter
    });
  }
}
```

At this point anything in your template subscribed to the filteredProjects$ observable will get the update filtered entities when setFilter is called.  For example:

**my.component.html**

```html
...
<app-project-list [projects]="filteredProjects$ | async"></app-project-list>
...
```

Comment: Nice, It worked . But i use multiple `filterFn` in entityMetaData and call each function based on requirement??

Answer (score 4):

An easy way is just to use your entity's model, say User

```
export const entityMetadata: EntityMetadataMap = {
  User: {
    filterFn: (entities: User[], { email, name }: Partial<User>) =>
      entities
        .filter((user) => (email? -1 < user.email.indexOf(email) : true))
        .filter((user) => (name ? -1 < user.name.indexOf(name) : true))
  }
};
```

and then in your component

```
constructor(private collectionService: UserCollectionService) {
  ...
}

filter() {
  this.collectionService.setFilter({ name: 'jan' });
  // or this.collectionService.setFilter({ name: 'jan', email: '@github.com' });
}
```